# How can I connect to a webservice through winIntet library in c++?

Tags: c++, web-services, wininet

I created a webService seems like that:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public WebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

the service reference is http://localhost:4653/WebService.asmx.

now, I need to access to this webservice through a cpp project.
for that, I'm using the winInet library that way:

```
HINTERNET handle = InternetOpen("Upload", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (handle)
{
    HINTERNET handleConnect = InternetConnect(handle, "localhost:4653", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, NULL, NULL);
    if (handleConnect)
    {
        if (HINTERNET handleOpenReq = HttpOpenRequest(handleConnect, TEXT("POST"), TEXT("/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld"), NULL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0))
        {
            if (HttpSendRequest(handleOpenReq, NULL, 0, NULL, 0))
                cout << "succeed" << endl;
            else
            {
                DWORD p = GetLastError();
            }
        }
```

however the HttpSendRequest does not succeed and GetLastError returns 12029, i.e 
The attempt to connect to the server failed.
how can I fix this problem, so it would connect well to the webService? are there some parameters I was sending wrong?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using InternetConnect, try to use InternetOpenUrl()

Comment: but the next function - HttpOpenRequest should get the handle that returns from InternetConnect

Comment: Can use InternetReadFile https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: OK.. but still I need to send data and not to read. then how can I do it??